# Ignore googlebot for Rack::Cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, googlebot, rack-cache

I'm using `Rack::Cache`, and google search bot triggers all my cache misses, so my cache is always full of pages that don't actually represent the most popular ones on my site, I can't seem to find how to ignore an IP or useragent for caching, has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for `Googlebot` in the user-agent string and skip caching if it is.

Search agent strings: http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/

Comment: This is a good route to take, I suppose I can wrap the cache method in  each controller action with this condition.